# Two LEDs for driveway gate

Tags: led

I have two 24v LED warning lights for a driveway gate, red and green. The gate opener unit has a circuit so that when the gate is open, it lights up the green LED and when it’s closed the light goes off. I need to be able to do the inverse of that, ie when then gate is closed, the red LED illuminates. I can provide constant 24v from the gate opener for the circuit as well as the switched 24v. I don’t know how to switch on the red light when the gate is shut, any help would be greatly welcomed!

*Table 1. '?'s to be fixed by OP. [Transistor]*

```
Gate        Contact   Existing   Desired
========    =======   ========   =======
Closed      ?         off        red
Opening     ?         ?          ?
Open        ?         green      off
Closing     ?         ?          ?
```

Comment: look for the `gate is closed` switch ... if there is one, then use it .... if there is not a switch, then install one to operate the red light

Comment: Spec sheet on the controller and LEDs or even a photo would greatly help.

Comment: Wow, a bit of soul searching by those voting off-topic may be in order. Device does not have the feature OP requires, electronic design (albeit rudimentary) is required. Whatever.

Comment: If you are going to edit your question to have it reopened can you address a point: "gate not open" is not the same as "gate closed" as it will be neither open nor closed. I'll add in a table for you to edit. Be sure to specify exactly under what conditions the switch contacts close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some passive components to power both LEDs with one output if it can supply enough current.

The circuit is assuming that the green LED is driven with a relay contact connected to 24V.  The 150 Ohm resistor needs to be a 5W power resistor and will get warm when the green LED in on.  When the Gate signal is low or the relay contact is open the power resistor will illuminate the red LED with minimal voltage drop causing barely discernible illumination in the green LED. The resistor values are calculated to give about 12mA LED current but this can be changed.  Use of Zenner diodes in series with the LEDs can reduce the power resistor dissipation as it does not have to clamp the voltage as much.

If the output contact is made to ground you would have to place the resistor in pull up arrangement.  If the output is driven high and low then you will not need the resistor.

Other arrangements are also possible depending on your device and how many wires you can afford to run to the LEDs (two is the minimum).  A datasheet for your controller would be useful information.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fovrrB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT:
For this to work with larger currents the resistor loading trick is not very practical as it needs to clamp below the glow voltage at the operating current of the other LED.  A simple SPDT relay is the correct and obvious solution. Select the contact rating to suit the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqLSEt.png)</sup>

Comment: I like the simplicity of your circuit.  I would presume the "Gate Signal" is a 24V switched between 24V and open rather than ground.  I would expect the current to be more more in the 350 mA to 1 Amp range (e.g. six serial Cree XP-E).

Comment: The gate actually has three states - fully closed, fully open, and moving.  You shouldn't indicate the gate is open when it has just moved slightly from fully closed. (Actually, there is a fourth state "fault" - when the limit switches indicate it is both open and closed.)

Comment: @PeterBennett  You are quite right. I was offering simple answers based on OPs low technological specifications, in part to elicit more details from them and also to prompt them into developing the ideas further.  It is clear that additional information is needed to make the Q and A complete, as it stands it has a minimum of value but more than zero.

Comment: @KalleMP - thanks, that makes sense even to me. I’ll give it a try. The implementation by the operator itself is only of limited value: The states are only open and closed. When it is moving the gate considers it to be in open state. Ditto in fault: if it’s not closed then it’s ‘open’, even if it’s stuck mid way and not moving. But your design I can definitely use, thanks for removing the fog and presenting it in the simplicity it should be. Cheers...